# Resource usage (% CPU) for given command on OS X

Tags: osx, performance, command, time, measure

The `time -v` command outputs *% CPU utilization* for a given command on Linux. How do I do this on OS X? The Linux/OS X difference is illustrated [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-summarize-detailed-system-resource-usage-with-time/). I would like to measure multi-core utilization across the total execution period of a short-running program, so `top` probably wouldn't work, as it measures/averages at particular points in time.

Comment: I think you can just use Activity Monitor for this.

Comment: No, Activity Monitor or `top` show resource usage in real time. If a program does not run for an extended period it will not show. Likewise these programs average over a pre-defined interval no from start to finish, such as `time`.

Comment: `El Capitan` (mine) has a highly modified version of `sar`.  I can't even grab the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no real alternative to the gnu `time` command. So, in the end I installed just that. On OS X gnu-time can be installed with homebrew: `brew install gnu-time`. Thereafter CPU utilization for a specific command can be measured using `gtime <command>`. A test shows that my program is indeed running concurrently: `1.73user 0.13system 0:01.61elapsed 115%CPU`.

Answer (score 2):

You man install the sysstat package and use the sar command.(https://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/installing-sar-monitoring-tools/)

**CPU Usage of ALL CPUs (sar -u)**

This gives the cumulative real-time CPU usage of all CPUs. “1 3″ reports for every 1 seconds a total of 3 times. Most likely you’ll focus on the last field “%idle” to see the cpu load.

```
$ sar -u 1 3
 Linux 2.6.18-194.el5PAE (dev-db)        03/26/2011      _i686_  (8 CPU)

  01:27:32 PM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait       %steal     %idle
  01:27:33 PM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
  01:27:34 PM       all      0.25      0.00      0.25      0.00      0.00     99.50
  01:27:35 PM       all      0.75      0.00      0.25      0.00      0.00     99.00
  Average:          all      0.33      0.00      0.17      0.00      0.00       99.50
```

Following are few variations:

```
sar -u Displays CPU usage for the current day that was collected until that point.
sar -u 1 3 Displays real time CPU usage every 1 second for 3 times.
sar -u ALL Same as “sar -u” but displays additional fields.
sar -u ALL 1 3 Same as “sar -u 1 3″ but displays additional fields.
sar -u -f /var/log/sa/sa10 Displays CPU usage for the 10day of the month from the sa10 file.
```

**CPU Usage of Individual CPU or Core (sar -P)**

If you have 4 Cores on the machine and would like to see what the individual cores are doing, do the following.

“-P ALL” indicates that it should displays statistics for ALL the individual Cores.

In the following example under “CPU” column 0, 1, 2, and 3 indicates the corresponding CPU core numbers.

```
  $ sar -P ALL 1 1
  Linux 2.6.18-194.el5PAE (dev-db)        03/26/2011      _i686_  (8 CPU)

  01:34:12 PM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
  01:34:13 PM       all     11.69      0.00      4.71      0.69      0.00     82.90
  01:34:13 PM         0     35.00      0.00      6.00      0.00      0.00     59.00
  01:34:13 PM         1     22.00      0.00      5.00      0.00      0.00     73.00
  01:34:13 PM         2      3.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     96.00
  01:34:13 PM         3      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
```

“-P 1″ indicates that it should displays statistics only for the 2nd Core. (Note that Core number starts from 0).

```
  $ sar -P 1 1 1
  Linux 2.6.18-194.el5PAE (dev-db)        03/26/2011      _i686_  (8 CPU)

  01:36:25 PM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
 01:36:26 PM         1      8.08      0.00      2.02      1.01      0.00     88.89
```

Following are few variations:

```
sar -P ALL Displays CPU usage broken down by all cores for the current day.
sar -P ALL 1 3 Displays real time CPU usage for ALL cores every 1 second for 3 times (broken down by all cores).
sar -P 1 Displays CPU usage for core number 1 for the current day.
sar -P 1 1 3 Displays real time CPU usage for core number 1, every 1 second for 3 times.
sar -P ALL -f /var/log/sa/sa10 Displays CPU usage broken down by all cores for the 10day day of the month from sa10 file.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, `sar` seems to integrate resource usage over a particular interval similar to `top`. Is it possible to use it similar to `time`, e.g. `time <command>`? Such that it integrates resource usage over the entire life time of a program.